# How to get the old file content which is erased due to file opened in write mode in python?

Tags: python, file-read

I was executing a python script to replace a word with another in all the files where the first word is found.

I accidentally opened my files in a folder in `w` mode and when the script finished executing, all my file contents were wiped out as I opened all files in the `w` mode instead of opening only the impacted files.

So is there any way to get back the contents of my files? Now all are empty with size `0`.

Comment: Only if you had those files backed up before running that script. `"w"` will write over everything in an existing file.

Comment: You should stop working on that drive and try ASAP some file undelete tools, depending on the OS you are working on. If you react rapidly, your should be able to recreate the files to their previous state with a high probability.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question to me. You should probably ask for help on SuperUser or somewhere similar.

Comment: I was looking for an option in python but it is not possible it seems. I tried with recovery tools like Phitorec, EaseUS and Recuva  but it didn't work either. Thank you all for your comments.